# Docker container write permissions

Tags: docker

I have some docker containers running on my machine, one of them being `container_1`

I am able to access `container_1`'s cli using

```
ant@ant~/D/m/l/db> docker exec -it container_1 bash
daemon@1997cc093b24:/$
```

This allows me to go to `container_1`'s cli but with no write permissions. The following commands give a permission denied error

```
ant@ant~/D/m/l/db> docker exec -it container_1 touch test.txt
bash: test.txt: Permission denied
ant@ant~/D/m/l/db>docker exec -it container_1 bash
daemon@1997cc093b24:/$ touch test.txt
bash: test.txt: Permission denied
```

Also tried using `--previleged` option but the problem persisted

```
ant@ant~/D/m/l/db> docker --previleged=true exec -it container_1 touch test.txt
bash: test.txt: Permission denied
```

So I have 2 questions

1. How do permissions in docker work?
2. Is this kind of modification to a docker filesystem recommended? If not why?

I have recently started using docker. Please tolorate the amature question. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 15):

Docker runs commands as a linux user which is bound to linux filesystem permissions. So the answer to this question depends on:

1. The uid you are running commands as (this defaults to root, but can be overridden in your image with a `USER` command in the Dockerfile, or on the `docker run` cli, or within your docker-compose.yml file).
2. The location where your command runs since you are using a relative path. This will default to `/`, but again can be overridden by changing the working directory in various ways, most often with the `WORKDIR` within the Dockerfile.
3. The directory and file permissions at that location.

Use `ls -al` inside the container to see the current permissions. Use `id` to see the current uid. With `docker exec` you can pass a flag to change the current user. And to change permissions, you can use `chmod` to change the permissions themselves, `chown` to change the user ownership, and `chgrp` to change the group ownership. e.g.:

```
docker exec -u root container_1 chmod 777 .
```

That command will allow any user to read or write to the current folder inside the container by running as the root user.

This assumes you haven't enabled any other security with SE Linux or AppArmor.